# How to read CPU cores available in Cloud Run environment?

Tags: google-cloud-run

We [see there are](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract) environmental variables available to read to get port/service/revision of a Cloud Run service.

In order to configure a multithreaded app, like gulp threads. How do you read how many cores are available?

Snippet:

```
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Comment: AFAIK, You don't have this information. But, at the end, what's the issue? What is the problem if you have 8 threads on 4 CPUs? Does it create issues? (I'm not so good in Python runtime behavior!)

Comment: Depending on what you base your docker image upon, I'm imaging we could determine the number of cores available at runtime.  If this is the case, then we could create a shell script that is the CMD that is executed which grabs the number of cores and uses that value to launch your gunicorn

Comment: Pentium10: I cannot confirm this from the documentation available. What is your concern?

Comment: If there is a CR app, that is essentially a worker for queue message processing, that has constant traffic, configuring optimal server with proper CPU based would make a lot of difference.

Comment: @Pentium10 if you're looking to handle constant traffic, Cloud Run is not for you. It times out after 15 minutes.

Comment: @Pentium10 Do the answers help you?

Comment: @MrTech Not quite. People think that 1 cpu allocated = 1 thread.  1vCPU is actually more powerful than a single core, especially if the physical CPUs have 8 cores.

Comment: @Pentium10 So if I understand correctly, you would like to know how many CPUs are assigned per running container?

Comment: @MrTech Yes, but not CPUs because that is basically vCPU which we control from deployment. I'd love to know how many "cores" are available to a running container.

Comment: @Pentium10 I've been unable to find documentation to allow this. So I suggest, if you wish to create a feature request for Cloud Run (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608076&template=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this information is not available from within Cloud Run.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to access multiple CPU cores in Cloud Run, you actually specify the number of cores during configuration. This is a constant value, so you don't need to check for it at runtime, so there is no feature to do so.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu

> By default Cloud Run container instances are allocated 1 CPU instance. You can change this number.